# `bool operator<(Contact&)' must take exactly two arguments

Tags: c++, comparison, operator-overloading, overloading, operator-keyword

I have

```
class Conatact{
.....
bool operator<(Contact &c);
};

bool operator<(Contact &c)
{
     return this.getName<c.getName();

}
```

it says `bool operator<(Contact&)' must take exactly two arguments 
when I try to change it to have two arguments

```
bool operator<(Contact &c)
{
     return this.getName<c.getName();

}
```

it says it must take exactly one argument

Answer (score 10):

I think you need to indicate to the compiler it's a member implementation by supplying a fully qualified name:

```
bool Conatact::operator<(Contact &c)
{
     return this->getName() < c.getName();
}
```

It would be a good idea to make your operator `const`, and to make the `Contact &c` `const` as well.

Without the scope resolution qualifier, the compiler thinks that you are defining a "free-standing" operator to compare contacts, in which case the operator would indeed need to take two arguments:

```
bool operator<(const Contact &lhs, const Contact &rhs) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Either that (and declare the operator as const), or preferably, declare and define the operator as a free function taking 2 Contact parameters.

Comment: @ArneMertz - a free function is often the right answer, but it's not necessarily correct. It allows, for example, implicit conversions on the left-hand side, and for something named `Contact` it's not obvious that this is appropriate.

Comment: @PeteBecker in that case, the `Contact` will hopefully not define conversion constructors and the free `operator<` won't hurt. If however someone would define a class that has an `operator Contact`, he would surely want to be able to compare it with other `Contact`s seamlessly.

Comment: @ArneMertz - there's a vague notion in the back of my mind about this, but I can't bring it forward and properly articulate it. So I won't pursue this, unless it becomes much clearer to me what it is that I'm talking about. `<g>`